# ImageView in android adapter convertView is measured as 0 width and 0 height

Tags: android, gridview, adapter

I am trying to add a scaled image in the adapter class in a gridView.
But the height and width of the iView is coming up as 0 for some reason when measured for scaling the image down.

Here is the code:

```
    override fun getView(i: Int, convertView: View?, viewGroup: ViewGroup): View {
        var cView = convertView
        val (_, name, company, _, imagePath) = mSitesData[i]

        if (cView == null) {
            val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
            cView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.sites_grid_layout, null)
        }
        val iView = cView!!.findViewById(R.id.imageview_cover_art) as ImageView
        val siteName = cView.findViewById(R.id.site_name) as TextView
        val siteCompany = cView.findViewById(R.id.company_name) as TextView

        if (imagePath.length<2){
            iView.setImageResource(R.drawable.camera_item)
        } else {

            val targetW = iView.getWidth() ***// GIVING 0 AS RESULT***
            val targetH = iView.getHeight()

            // Get the dimensions of the bitmap
            val bmOptions = BitmapFactory.Options() // Returns Option Object
            bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true // So it does not run out of memory if image is big
            BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath, bmOptions) // But can still query the size of the image
            val photoW = bmOptions.outWidth
            val photoH = bmOptions.outHeight

            // Determine how much to scale down the image
            val scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW / targetW, photoH / targetH)

            // Decode the image file into a Bitmap sized to fill the View
            bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false
            bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor

            val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath, bmOptions)
            iView.setImageBitmap(bitmap)

        }

        siteName.text = name
        siteCompany.text = company
        return cView
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The width and height of the child are not known until the item view is created in getView () and bound to the listview and requestLayout () occurs. This is a natural process in terms of the layout process, and it will probably get the width and height values from the time the generated view is recycled. There may be a way to override onLayout on the ImageView to handle it on the first call.

Comment: These lines don't create the view? if (cView == null).....
            
            cView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.sites_grid_layout, null)

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this

```
 imageView.measure(0, 0);
        imageView.getMeasuredHeight();
        imageView.getMeasuredWidth();
```

Comment: Then use ongloballayoutchangelistener